# So I got this problem while importing a csv file (It is in the same directory as my Python 3 file)

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, decode

The following code line :

```
file = pd.read_csv('okstodo.csv')
```

gives me the following error:

---

```
UnicodeDecodeError Traceback (most recent call last) pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: `f = codecs.open('/test/input.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore');
pd.read_csv(f)` If worse comes to worse, and you think the file may have some bad characters in it for whatever reason. This might help. The `errors` parameter tells the codec how to handle unrecognized data, assuming you're using the right encoding. First see if it can be fixed without this using the encoding param of read_csv, or what others suggest.

Comment: Y am I downvoted for this. Please guide as I have reached question limit

Comment: Don't take one downvoted question hard. It happens. If you're interested in improving your questions to get better ratings, maybe try to apply some advice from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Todd thanks a lot.......will certainly consider your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
data = pd.read_csv("okstodo.csv", encoding = 'unicode_escape', engine ='python')
```

Also check this [standard-encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) use in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

`read_csv` takes an encoding option to deal with files in different formats. I mostly use read_csv('file', encoding = "ISO-8859-1"), or alternatively encoding = "utf-8" for reading, and generally utf-8 for to_csv.

You can also use one of several alias options like 'latin' instead of 'ISO-8859-1' (see python docs, also for numerous other encodings you may encounter).

See relevant Pandas documentation, python docs examples on csv files, and plenty of related questions here on SO. A good background resource is What every developer should know about unicode and character sets.

To detect the encoding (assuming the file contains non-ascii characters), you can use enca (see man page) or file -i (linux) or file -I (osx) (see man page).